# Picture on phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I would like to put photos in my phpmyadmin database but I can't find the solution that allows me to do so. I made an image array with a varchar but I can't find the path that allows to put an image. I thank you in advance for helping a young beginner ❤️

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to store the image as a file on disk and put the path to the file in the database (as a varchar or some other text type), then your application references the file instead of loading the BLOB data directly from the database. There are performance reasons that are well documented elsewhere that explain the intricate details better than I can, but basically the database slows and the amount of disk space it takes up expands as you store the images in the database.

If you decide to defy that advice and store the image directly in the database, you shouldn't be using phpMyAdmin as your main interface. Don't get me wrong, it's fully capable of uploading the image, but presumably you'll have some custom application interface that you should be using instead that also does application-level logic. But that's not what you asked, so to do this in phpMyAdmin, there should be a "Browse" button near the field on the phpMyAdmin Insert page. This requires your column be some appropriate sort of binary such as BLOB.

[image: Insert page]

Comment: you are the best, thank you for taking the time to answer me, I will listen to your advice and put the path directly into the database in Varchar. to do this you just have to put "image/nameofimage.jgp"?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly the right idea. You might decide to store the images out of the web share or as part of it depending on your design needs, but the idea is the same either way and you would then use your application logic to point to the correct location based on what you pull out of the database. You can either use the actual file name or rename it based on your needs, too, but that would be part of your application and the specific needs of your program.